# ReactJS : Render dynamic child elements inside a custom component

Tags: reactjs

I've created a generic component which renders dynamic content. Idea is to render whatever child elements are provided inside the custom component. Code snippet below:-

```
<DropDownMenu {...profileDropDown}>
   <div className="profile-drop-down-settings">
     profileProps.map(function(data, index) {
       <span>{data}</span>
     });
   </div>
</DropDownMenu>
```

Dropdown component (render part) :-

```
render() {
  const config = this.props;
  return (
    <div class="drop-down-menu">
     {this.props.children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Now the issue is, I'm not able to run the map function. It throws an error stating it can't access the `data` variable. I'm new to react, am I missing anything?

Comment: <span>{data}</span>. At this line span tag misses tag end.  May be a typo here.  Also cover your map function with curly braces

Comment: also missing the `return` statement in the function passed to the map

Comment: @JayabalajiJ Updated the tag, still it throws reference error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've setup a simple [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/z3n4462zr3) to showcase what you're trying to do.

### In essence:

- `App` renders `Container` which is given children by `App`

  - the logic for how the children are constructed are controlled by `App`
- `Container` simply renders those children as is

Hope this example is a replica of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: please consider marking the answer as useful if you found it so :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

```
<DropDownMenu {...profileDropDown}>
   <div className="profile-drop-down-settings">
     { profileProps.map(function(data, index) {
       return <span{data}</span>
     }); }
   </div>
</DropDownMenu>
```